# How to swap values of two variables without using temp variable?

Tags: ruby

I have two variables `x` and `y`

```
x = 1
y = 2
```

I want to swap their value using one line of code without using a temp variable

```
temp = y
y = x
x = temp
```

Any idea how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try something like this

```
x, y = y, x
```